# GWT DataGrid: missing sort arrow - 404 error

Tags: sorting, gwt, datagrid

I have some problem with DataGrid in GWT. I am trying to implement a DataGrid for my own type, using mainly example from the official [GWT Showcase](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid). I was able to work out mostly everything I needed (so far), but there seems to be a problem with sorting that I cannot solve.

It seems that sorting mechanism works (I did not implement sorting on backend yet, but I can see that proper calls are made). The problem is that each click on the column header causes following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/sk.tuke.threat.management.Application/clear.cache.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

And the expected arrow icon showing that the column is sorted is substituted with the browser icon for missing picture resource. It at least seems that it gets substituted, for a brief moment after the click it seems that the arrow flashed there, however, then the 404 icon takes place.

Can somebody point me out what can be the problem? Comparing my code with [GWT Showcase](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid) example I cannot see where might be the problem. I only substituted the ListHandler for AsyncHandler, since I am getting the data from the server, but besides that, no change that in my eyes could case some problems with resources.

Comment: Start from simple one (http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid). Did u face same issue there?

Comment: I face the same problem when I started working with CellBrowser.. there is some kind of bug or maybe a problem in my setup. However, when I build the WAR and deploy to Tomcat (so not using GWT dev server) it works fine. So right now, because of the lack of time, I do not try to resolve it, since it is only a visual problem that disappears in production.